# How to Formulas Template used Jxls

Tags: java, jxls

I used Jxls. I want to used Formulas Template.

Template

[image]

result

[image]

Why Just line 1 is #value error..?

Comment: Similar example works fine for me. Try to change the format of your template cells to be number. If it does not help you may want to create an issue in jxls bug tracker.

Comment: Double click  '#value' cell ..then text format of cell changed normal format.! And ctrl+z... then clean error...

Comment: can you share your code to see what you are doing?